# How to extract the extra content loaded in a web page

Tags: c#, parsing, c#-4.0, html-parsing, web-scraping

How to extract the extra content loaded in a web page, which will not be visible in view page source. The extra content is being loaded using ajax. This data can be seen under NET tab using firebug. How to extract this data using c# code.

Comment: plenty of information out there already just need to search...http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%23+scraping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways :

1- You can use `webbrowser` to load the same page and get the `active document`.

2- You can replicate the `ajax call made`, and use that to get the extra bits that are appended to the document.

And reading your linkedin example above:

When you select the checkbox a ajax call is made , which brings back results and populates the table.You can see that call using firebug console window and see the post parameter and replicate them to get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your application in the first place, if you are using c# application as the client for reading a web page, then the the ajax content may not be visible until you put in a javascript engine.

if you are serving the said pages, you only have to log the request response of the server.

More specific question would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

That extra content is dynamically generated by ajax (for eg: Gridview is generated as table), it is stored in browser's memory. and can be viewed by client side debugging tools (IE has developer tools option).
Once you do a post back, all the control's values are available for C#.

If you are saying extra content, can you please clarify what exactly you are trying to extract using c#?

Comment: In the web page, there are check boxes based on your check box selection the content in particular section is getting changed. After selecting the check box i opened page source , even in page source also the default content is being showed not the changed content after selecting check box.

Comment: yes, if the content is generated by ajax, then it will not be shown in view source. however, control data can be accessed, now which data you want to extract? please give a sample code if possible.

Comment: I found similar functionality in linkedin. [Example](http://www.linkedin.com/csearch/results?csrfToken=ajax%3A4408066263485336459&keywords=crm#facets=pplSearchOrigin%3DFCTD%26keywords%3Dcrm%26search%3DSubmit%26facet_CCR%3Dus%253A0%26openFacets%3DCCR%252CJO%252CI)
I want the companies name to be extracted after checking country check box.